# Internet does on connect on Ubuntu as Virutalbox guest on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have ubuntu 12.04 running on virtual box on Windows host. I have been using it for last couple of months and internet was working absolutely fine until couple of days back. The internet speed within virutalbox has decreased a lot and most of the times the internet does not even connect for long. Sometimes it connects but runs for like 1-2 minutes and then disconnects.

I'll give you a few situations ---

- apt-get running fine, dropbox not running, all web browsers showing "Unable to access the network".
- None of the above running
- all run but only for a couple of minutes and then internet speed goes to zero.

In all browsers it appears to be some resolving issue. Browsers say it "Could not find server".

I searched on the internet. Some asked to use some "VBoxManage" command to change or configure the `nat resolver` or something. I even did that but in vain.

I cannot figure out what to do?

Comment: How have you configured the VirtualBox network adapter that your Ubuntu VM is seeing? If you leave it at the default "NAT" then you should be fine. Also make sure you have the Guest Additions installed on Ubuntu...

Comment: @BigChris
I have guest addition installed already. How do I configure the Network Adapter that you are saying?

Comment: Shutdown your VM -> click the settings for your VM -> click "Network"on first tab -> check that the network dropdown is "NAT"

Comment: @BigChris I checked  and it was NAT already!